# Função que retorna todas combinações de uma string

Tags: python

Olá! Estou tentando desenvolver um script para que eu possa revisar alguns conteúdos abordados enquanto estudava e treinar a minha lógica e propus para mim um desafio: Desenvolver um script capaz de retornar todas combinações possíveis de uma string. Porém, vejo em meu script diversas coisas que tornam-o infeficáz.

```python
from random import shuffle
from math import factorial


def combinations(str):
    allcomb = []  # Aqui aramazena todas combinações
    word = [l for l in str]  
    for l in str:
        t = 0  # Quantas combinações uma letra tem
        while t != factorial(len(str)) / len(str):
            word2 = word.copy()
            shuffle(word2)  # Embaralha a lista da palavra
            print(word2)
            if word2 not in allcomb:
                t += 1
                allcomb.append(word2)

    print(allcomb)


combinations('eae')
```

minhas dúvidas são:
Como posso fazer para que o computador embaralhe as strings com mais eficiência? Pois deste modo, ele está fazendo isso de forma aleatória, e quando aumentar a quantidade de letras, a probabilidade de ele achar a unica palavra que falta é muito baixa.

A segunda é que há um erro lógico. Na palavra que testei como input temos duas letras repetidas. Quando ele verificar, verá que há duas combinações iguais 'eae' e 'eae'. Algo que a verficação não aceitará, tornando isso um looping infinito.

Bom, se achar que consegue me ajudar, por favor, me contate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL:DR

Usar [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) ao invés de [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) pois `permutations` retornará as possibilidades de um [Arranjo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria#Arranjos) enquanto `combinations` as possibilidades de uma [Combinação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria#Combina%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Ou seja, em combinações `ab` e `ba` são idênticos pois sua ordem não importa, porém você está falando de palavras então `medo` e `demo` são palavras diferentes, por isso o uso de [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
from itertools import permutations

def arranjos(palavra):
    resultado = set()

    for i in range(1, len(palavra) + 1):
        resultado.update("".join(r) for r in permutations(palavra, i))

    return resultado
```

---

## Explicação

Se você for ver a teoria de [Análise Combinatória](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria), você não quer uma [Combinação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria#Combina%C3%A7%C3%A3o), você quer um [Arranjo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria#Arranjos), pois na Combinação a ordem do que você está combinando **não** importa, já no Arranjo esta ordem faz diferença.

### Arranjo com repetição

A **ordem faz diferença e objetos podem ser repetidos**, um bom exemplo é quando você quer criar uma senha numérica.

Imagine que a senha tem 2 dígitos e você pode usar apenas os números de zero a nove, é evidente que a senha `12` é diferente da senha `21` por isso temos um arranjo, e não um combinação. Também é possível para uma pessoa criar uma senha `11` ou `22`, por isso utilizamos um arranjo com repetição, que nada mais é que o [produto cartesiano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_cartesiano) de `0123456789` com ele mesmo. O módulo `itertools` implementa este algoritmo de maneira performática na função [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Veja o exemplo da senha:

```
from itertools import product

arranjo_com_rep = product("0123456789", repeat=2)
# ['00', '01', '02', ..., '98', '99']
```

### Arranjo sem repetição

A **ordem faz diferença e objetos NÃO podem ser repetidos**, acredito que é o que você está tentando fazer. Usando arranjo comum você está dizendo: *"Quais são as possibilidades se eu misturar e pegar N letras desta palavra?"*. Ou seja, você está usando apenas as letras que estão na palavra sem repeti-las.

Um exemplo de uso seria, "tenho uma escada com 2 degraus e 3 garrafas (garrafas 'a', 'b' e 'c'). de quantas maneiras diferentes posso dispor minhas garrafas nestes degraus?".

Vale lembrar que uma [Permutações Simples](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinat%C3%B3ria#Permuta%C3%A7%C3%B5es_simples) nada mais é que um arranjo sem repetição onde o tamanho do agrupamento de elementos do resultado é igual ao tamanho dos elementos que estão sendo combinados. Ou seja, uma permutação simples nada mais é que "embaralhar" os elementos.

O módulo `itertools` implementa este algoritmo de maneira performática na função [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). Repare que se você não passar o segundo parâmetro para a função, ela usa o tamanho do iterável que ele recebeu. Dito isso, fica claro que se você quiser fazer um arranjo, basta passar o segundo parâmetro definindo o tamanho dos conjuntos de resultado, se quiser uma permutação basta não passar o segundo parâmetro.

```
from itertools import permutations

arranjo_com_rep = permutations("abc", 2)
# [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]

permutacao = permutations("abc")
# [('a', 'b', 'c'),
#  ('a', 'c', 'b'),
#  ('b', 'a', 'c'),
#  ('b', 'c', 'a'),
#  ('c', 'a', 'b'),
#  ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

### Combinação sem repetição

Apesar de não ser o que você precisa para este caso é importante você entender que **combinações NÃO levam em conta a ordem dos elementos**.

Imagine que você tem 5 alunos em uma turma  quer saber quantos grupos de 2 membros você poderia formar com eles.

Você poderá calcular quais grupos poderiam ser formados usando o método [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). Veja que ordem não importa, pois um grupo formado pelos alunos "A" e "C" é o mesmo grupo formado pelos alunos "C" e "A".

```
from itertools import combinations

combinacoes = combinations("ABCDE", 2)
# [('A', 'B'),
#  ('A', 'C'),
#  ('A', 'D'),
#  ('A', 'E'),
#  ('B', 'C'),
#  ('B', 'D'),
#  ('B', 'E'),
#  ('C', 'D'),
#  ('C', 'E'),
#  ('D', 'E')]
```

### Combinação com repetição

É mesma situação anterior, porém a repetição dos elementos é permitida.

Imagine que você quer comprar um sorvete com 4 bolas em uma sorveteria que possui 3 sabores disponíveis. De quantos modos diferentes você pode fazer esta compra?

Você poderá calcular combinações com repetição usando o método [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
combinacoes = combinations_with_replacement("ABC", 4)
# [('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
#  ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
#  ('A', 'A', 'A', 'C'),
#  ('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
#  ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
#  ('A', 'A', 'C', 'C'),
#  ('A', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
#  ('A', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
#  ('A', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
#  ('A', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
#  ('B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
#  ('B', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
#  ('B', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
#  ('B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
#  ('C', 'C', 'C', 'C')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Especificamente no caso do Python você pode usar o [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
from itertools import combinations

all_combinations = set()

my_string = "pernambuco"  # <- já não tem repetições de caracteres

for i in range(1,len(my_string)+1):
    for j in combinations(my_string, i):
        all_combinations.add("".join(j))

print(all_combinations)
```

O uso do `set()` é para restringir as repetições, apesar de que elas não ocorrerão no exemplo já que a *string* `Pernambuco` não tem letras repetidas.